# Sony Camera API over USB

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

Is the Sony camera API available over USB or bluetooth?

Specifically I want to be able to download pictures as they are taken (picture mode) on a A5000 and I cannot use WiFi.

Any information or links to appropriate USB tethering protocols would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Camera Remote API is only supported over WiFi, so no BT or USB connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for the response mate. I assumed this to be the case but couldn't find any confirmation. I would upvote this answer but it won't let me as I'm new to SO.

Comment: Sony provides a "Remote Camera Control" app for OSX and Windows (http://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/imsoft/Mac/rcc/us.html). Does this use the documented API or something else? A lot of my work with the Sony API needs to be done via desktop (not mobile) and using a wifi based API is kind of a pain. It would be AMAZING if the same api set was somehow available via USB.

Comment: Yes USB would be good. Also add Ethernet support for applications where reliability is needed, and make them PoE powered. Image quality much better than standard IP cameras. Also support auto on, when AC power comes back online for unattended setups.

Answer (score 0):

I too am looking for this functionality.  We are trying to integrate a DSC-HX60V into a UAS payload to provide imagery for a seried of field experiments and the camera will need to be triggered by the flight controller.  Since the flight controller does not have wifi we need a tethered control option.

Answer (score 0):

For reference if anyone is trying to control camera trigger,  zoom via USB there is this option. It converts Rc pwm signals to sonys MULTI protocol. Would love to know how this multi terminal works so to control direct from embedded system.

http://www.gentles.ltd.uk/gentwire/multi.htm